# Filtering with newest version of rows in three different sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, formulas

My problem is finding a viable solution for identifying an ID-column in three different spreadsheets and then return the row with latest update time.

Below is example, with the different spreadsheets represented. There are many more columns in the sheets, but these are the two that are measured (they are in date-time format IRL). The first two are event-triggered and the third is manual.

```
NEW DEAL CREATED         NEW STAGE UPDATE       IMPORT (DATAPROOFING)               
+--------+------------+  +-------+-----------+  +-------+-----------+
| ID     |UPDATE TIME |  |ID     |UPDATE TIME|  |ID     |UPDATE TIME|
+--------+------------+  +-------+-----------+  +-------+-----------+
| 233    | 21/05/2015 |  |233    |21/05/2015 |  |233    |01/04/2015 |
| 234    | 22/05/2016 |  |233    |22/05/2015 |  |143    |31/02/2016 |
| 325    | 02/05/2016 |  |234    |22/05/2015 |  |847    |11/07/2015 |
| 326    | 01/01/2016 |  |234    |23/05/2015 |  |746    |19/08/2016 |
| 327    | 03/04/2016 |  |233    |24/05/2015 |  |432    |05/03/2015 |
| 328    | 05/03/2015 |  |233    |24/05/2015 |  |342    |20/01/2016 |
+--------+------------+  +-------+-----------+  +-------+-----------+
```

The data I want is then a single row for each ID, returning the row of the sheet with the latest update date.

I am using Google Spreadsheets for analytics for our CRM in the company. Here I import the deals from our customers, but I have to use both Zapier and manual imports, which means many duplicates, despite using different sheets.

I have not succeeded in creating a filtering function, but my current one goes like this:

```
=iferror(
if(
iferror(
index(Import!$N:$N,(match(Calculations!$B110,Import!$A:$A,0)),1),"IMPORTERROR")=MAX({index(Import!$N:$N,(match(Calculations!$B110,Import!$A:$A,0)),1),iferror(index(Zapier!$BV:$BV,(match(Calculations!$B110,Zapier!$A:$A,0))),""),index(Pipedrive!$BV:$BV,(match(Calculations!$B110,Pipedrive!$A:$A,0)))}),
"ImportConvert",
(if(
iferror(
index(Zapier!$BV:$BV,(match(Calculations!$B110,Zapier!$A:$A,0))),"ZAPIERERROR")=MAX({index(Import!$N:$N,(match(Calculations!$B110,Import!$A:$A,0)),1),iferror(index(Zapier!$BV:$BV,(match(Calculations!$B110,Zapier!$A:$A,0))),""),index(Pipedrive!$BV:$BV,(match(Calculations!$B110,Pipedrive!$A:$A,0)))}),
"Zapier",
(if(
iferror(
index(Pipedrive!$BV:$BV,(match(Calculations!$B110,Pipedrive!$A:$A,0))),"PIPEDRIVEERROR")=MAX({index(Import!$N:$N,(match(Calculations!$B110,Import!$A:$A,0)),1),iferror(index(Zapier!$BV:$BV,(match(Calculations!$B110,Zapier!$A:$A,0))),""),index(Pipedrive!$BV:$BV,(match(Calculations!$B110,Pipedrive!$A:$A,0)))}),
"Pipedrive",
"NONE"))))),"")
```

It doesn't quite work, as it requires the ID to be present in all sheets. This is not the case, as the manual import is not filled often.

I am not skilled in programming and recognize that an array-solution might be present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The answer in short:**

```
=max(ARRAYFORMULA(if(Sheet2!A:A = A1,Sheet2!B:B,0)),ARRAYFORMULA(if(Sheet3!A:A = A1,Sheet3!B:B,0)),ARRAYFORMULA(if(Sheet4!A:A = A1,Sheet4!B:B,0)))
```

if you get a bunch of numbers instead of dates force the formatting on the column to date. the formulas seem to confuse auto formatting sometimes.

**A bit of explanation:**

This formula assumes that A1 on the current sheet is an ID number

```
max(ARRAYFORMULA(if(Sheet3!A:A = A1,Sheet3!B:B,0)))
```

The arrayformula applies the if to each cell in column A in sheet3 and puts the results in a list/array. the list will contain the dates for every ID in sheet3 that matches the ID in A1 and a bunch of zeros. taking max of that list gives us the highest(most recent) date for that ID in sheet3.

Then we feed that max the arrayformula for each of the other sheets we will get most recent date for associated with the ID on any of the sheets

```
=max(ARRAYFORMULA(if(Sheet2!A:A = A1,Sheet2!B:B,0)),ARRAYFORMULA(if(Sheet3!A:A = A1,Sheet3!B:B,0)),ARRAYFORMULA(if(Sheet4!A:A = A1,Sheet4!B:B,0)))
```

**To find the oldest:**

change the 0 in the if's to NOW() or NOW() + something ridiculous if you are working with future dates and take the min

```
=min(ARRAYFORMULA(if(Sheet2!A:A = A1,Sheet2!B:B,NOW())),ARRAYFORMULA(if(Sheet3!A:A = A1,Sheet3!B:B,NOW())),ARRAYFORMULA(if(Sheet4!A:A = A1,Sheet4!B:B,NOW())))
```

**An alternative:**
If you want to know what sheet and cell the date is on you have to use nested IFs and matches:

```
=if(AND(max(ARRAYFORMULA(if(Sheet3!A:A = A1,Sheet3!B:B,0))) > max(ARRAYFORMULA(if(Sheet2!A:A = A1,Sheet2!B:B,0))), max(ARRAYFORMULA(if(Sheet3!A:A = A1,Sheet3!B:B,0))) > max(ARRAYFORMULA(if(Sheet4!A:A = A1,Sheet4!B:B,0)))),"Sheet3!B"&match(max(ARRAYFORMULA(if(Sheet3!A:A = A1,Sheet3!B:B,0))),Sheet3!B:B),if(max(ARRAYFORMULA(if(Sheet4!A:A = A1,Sheet4!B:B,0))) > max(ARRAYFORMULA(if(Sheet2!A:A = A1,Sheet2!B:B,0))),"Sheet4!B"&match(max(ARRAYFORMULA(if(Sheet4!A:A = A1,Sheet4!B:B,0))),Sheet4!B:B),"Sheet2!B"&match(max(ARRAYFORMULA(if(Sheet2!A:A = A1,Sheet2!B:B,0))),Sheet2!B:B)))
```

**A little something that might be useful:**

I made this to fill column A on my Sheet1 with a non repeating list of IDs from the other three sheets.

```
=sort(UNIQUE({UNIQUE(Sheet2!A:A); UNIQUE(Sheet3!A:A);UNIQUE(Sheet4!A:A)}))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that was just what I needed!